# Dynamic write XML using HTML running python script

Tags: python, xml, cgi

I am trying to write XML document by taking input on an Html page and running a python script..

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/cgi-bin/dscr.cgi " method="post">
serverID:<input type= "text" name="field1" id="textbox" /> </br>
name:<input type= "text" name="field2" id="textbox2" /> </br>
host:<input type= "text" name="field3" id="textbox3" /> </br>
port:<input type= "text" name="field4" id="textbox4" /> </br>
proto:<input type= "text" name="field5" id="textbo5x" /> </br>
user:<input type= "text" name="field6" id="textbox6" /> </br>
password:<input type= "text" name="field7" id="textbox7" /> </br>
key:<input type= "text" name="field8" id="textbox8" /> </br>
companyName:<input type= "text" name="field9" id="textbox9" /> </br>
officeAddress:<input type= "text" name="field10" id="textbox10" /> </br>
state:<input type= "text" name="field11" id="textbox11" /> </br>
country:<input type= "text" name="field12" id="textbox12" /> </br>
lAdmin:<input type= "text" name="field13" id="textbox13" /> </br>
phone:<input type= "text" name="field14" id="textbox14" /> </br>
mobile:<input type= "text" name="field15" id="textbox15" /> </br>
email:<input type= "text" name="field16" id="textbox16" /> </br>
designation:<input type= "text" name="field17" id="textbox17" /> </br>
reportingMgr:<input type= "text" name="field18" id="textbox18" /> </br>

<input type="submit" id="btn" value ="send"  />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the python script being called:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#author__    = "Devanshu Misra"
# __copyright__ = "Copyright 2017, ACPL Systems Pvt. Ltd."
# __license__   = "proprietary"
# __version__   = "1.0.1"
# __status__    = "Under Development"

import cgi, cgitb
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import os

base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
xml_file = os.path.join(base_path, "company.xml")



form = cgi.FieldStorage()

serverId = form.getvalue("field1")
name = form.getvalue("field2")
host = form.getvalue("field3")
port = form.getvalue("field4")
proto = form.getvalue("field5")
user = form.getvalue("field6")
password = form.getvalue("field7")
key = form.getvalue("field8")
company = form.getvalue("field9")
officeAddr = form.getvalue("field10")
state = form.getvalue("field11")
country = form.getvalue("field12")
ladmin = form.getvalue("field13")
phone = form.getvalue("field14")
mobile = form.getvalue("field15")
email = form.getvalue("field16")
designation = form.getvalue("field17")
reportingMgr = form.getvalue("field18")


tree = et.parse(xml_file)

root = tree.getroot()

new_server = et.SubElement(root, "server",
                        id = str(serverId))
new_name = et.SubElement(new_server, "name")
new_host = et.SubElement(new_server, "host")
new_port = et.SubElement(new_server, "port")
new_proto = et.SubElement(new_server, "proto")
new_user = et.SubElement(new_server, "user")
new_password = et.SubElement(new_server, "password")
new_key = et.SubElement(new_server, "key")
new_company_name = et.SubElement(new_server, "companyName")
new_address = et.SubElement(new_server, "address")
new_office_address = et.SubElement(new_address, "officeAddress")
new_state = et.SubElement(new_address, "state")
new_country = et.SubElement(new_address, "country")
new_contacts = et.SubElement(new_server, "contacts")
new_ladmin = et.SubElement(new_contacts, "ladmin")
new_phone = et.SubElement(new_contacts, "phone")
new_mobile = et.SubElement(new_contacts, "mobile")
new_email = et.SubElement(new_contacts, "email")
new_designation = et.SubElement(new_contacts, "designation")
new_reportingManager = et.SubElement(new_contacts, "reportingManager")



new_name.text = name
new_host.text = host
new_port.text = port
new_proto.text = proto
new_user.text = user
new_password.text = password
new_key.text = key
new_company_name.text = company
new_office_address.text = officeAddr
new_state.text = state
new_country.text = country
new_ladmin.text = ladmin
new_phone.text = phone
new_mobile.text = mobile
new_email.text = email
new_designation.text = designation
new_reportingManager.text = reportingMgr





tree.write(xml_file)
```

This is the format of my XML file:

```
<data>
  <server id="bvcbv">
    <name>c</name>
    <host>bvc</host>
    <port>bvc</port>
    <proto>bc</proto>
    <user>bv</user>
    <password>cb</password>
    <key>vcb</key>
    <companyName>vc</companyName>
    <address>
      <officeAddress>bc</officeAddress>
      <state>bvc</state>
      <country>bvc</country>
    </address>
    <contacts>
      <ladmin>bvc</ladmin>
      <phone>bvc</phone>
      <mobile>bvc</mobile>
      <email>bv</email>
      <designation>cbv</designation>
      <reportingManager>cb</reportingManager>
    </contacts>
  </server>
</data>
```

On execution, I get an Internal Server Error, but no traceback calls when i check the python script, and all the tags are written in the XML but with no values to them which the user is inputting. Why is this happening and how do i resolve this?

Comment: For troubleshooting, you can use traceback package. Import it, wrap the statement/s you're doubtful about in try-except block. In except block, you can use `traceback.print_exc()` to print the traceback.

Comment: @LakshmikantDeshpande should i wrap the whole of the code in the try block, as nothing seems doubtful as such?

Comment: Why not ? You can remove it later.

Comment: @LakshmikantDeshpande I just tried that, but when i use `python dscr.cgi` instead of giving me any traceback calls, it just prints the tags of the xml file for me. And the same result when i try to use it through the main HTML page by calling the script.

Comment: Traceback should include useful debugging information. It must be printing tags, because the library developer must've programmed it that way. Here's a [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) where you can read more about it. Although I'm not familiar with cgi, I'd try by debugging the code using pdb or PyCharm's debugger (which is kinda cool (perhaps it might be using pdb .. I don't know about it)).

Comment: @LakshmikantDeshpande thank you sir, since i was stuck for a long time, i chose another way to do it where i am using a php script as a mediator between my cgi and the html doc

Comment: no problem. Let me know if you need any other help :)